# How can I sent mail to multiple receivers with html 5, asp.net (without PHP)

Tags: html, asp.net

I write web site and I have a contact form for send mail.I use Formspree to send mail,it works for one receiver.But I want send email to multiple receivers.I cant find any information.Please help me.

Thanks..

My html code is like as below:

```
<form id="contact" action="https://formspree.io/emailname@gmail.com" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="contact_author" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="_replyto" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="contact_subject" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter Subject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="contact_content" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div id="gglcptch_recaptcha_760104045" class="gglcptch_recaptcha">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-btn dark">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

Is there anybody use this method, please share with me..

Comment: For ASP.NET environment, try using `System.Net.Mail` namespace in code-behind. It has `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` class which can be used to compose and send email to multiple recipients by setting `To` and `Cc`/`Bcc` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.MyWebsiteDomainName.com", 25);

smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@MyWebsiteDomainName.com", "myIDPassword");
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

//Setting From , To and CC
mail.From = new MailAddress("info@MyWebsiteDomainName", "MyWeb Site");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@MyWebsiteDomainName"));
mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("MyEmailID@gmail.com"));

smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just loop through the different addresses and keep

```
private List<string> Addresses = new List<string>
```

You can then fill the list however you like. I just add them manually here for the sake of simplicity:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Addresses.Add("FirstEmail");
    Addresses.Add("SecondEmail");
    // Now loop through the addresses in the list and send an email for each one
    foreach (string s in Adresses)
    {
        SendMail(s);
    }
}
private void SendMail(string Receiver)
{
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.To.Add(Receiver);
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("another@mail-address.com");
    mailMessage.Subject = "ASP.NET e-mail test";
    mailMessage.Body = "Hello world,\n\nThis is an ASP.NET test e-mail!";
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.your-isp.com");
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

Hope this helps!